# How to increase timeout limit on Vercel Serverless functions

Tags: javascript, next.js, timeout, serverless, vercel

I have an API endpoint on a NextJS project that needs longer than 60s to run. I'm on a pro Vercel plan but for some reason cannot get the timeout limit to increase.

At the endpoint itself I've tried

```
export const maxDuration = 300
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

which doesn't seem to do anything, I also tried adding a `vercel.json` file at the top level (above `/src`) like so:

```
{
    "functions": {
        "pages/api/**": {
            "memory": 3008,
            "maxDuration": 300
        },
    }
}
```

Which again isn't working. I've combed through the documentation (mostly [here](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/duration)) and also a handful of threads ([one example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56447)), none of which have helped.

I'm running NextJs version `13.5.6`, am definitely on a pro plan, and Node v18, what am I doing wrong? Am really unsure of what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done seems to be a mix of the Pages Router way the and the App Router way of doing it. Try to do it like in this example below:

**With Pages Router (`/pages/api/my-function/handler.ts`):**

```
export const config = {
  maxDuration: 5, // 5 seconds
};

export default function handler(
  request: NextApiRequest,
  response: NextApiResponse,
) {
  response.status(200).json({});
}
```

**With App Router (`/app/api/my-function/route.ts`):**

```
export const maxDuration = 5; // 5 seconds
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response('{}', { status: 200 });
}
```

If you want to override the maximum duration of a function for your whole project when using Vercel, you can do it in `vercel.json` (I think this is only valid for the App Router):

```
{
  "functions": {
    "app/api/**/*": {
      "maxDuration": 5
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about all this on the [official docs](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/configuring-functions/duration).